# visp_camera_calibration doesn't write the calibartion.ini file

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do all the proceding told on the tutorial for the calibration of an external camera from the ROS wiki.

The camera i'm trying to calibrate is the one on the Parrot ARDrone.

Everything works fine and after calling the calibrate service I get the stdDevErrs output as the tutorial says, but the calibration.ini file isn't saved anywhere.

Any ideas as what might be the problem?

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52567/visp_camera_calibration-doesn%27t-write-the-calibartion.ini-file/) by [jara](https://answers.ros.org/users/3985/jara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-01-17**:
I posted your question on visp-user mailing-list, I hope the package authors will be able to answer it directly :)

**Comment by [jara](https://answers.ros.org/users/3985/jara/) on 2013-01-17**:
many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As explained on the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/visp_camera_calibration/Tutorials/CalibrationExperimentalCamera, the calibration.ini file should be in your $HOME/.ros directory

Fabien

---

Originally posted by [Fabien Spindler](https://answers.ros.org/users/3990/fabien-spindler/) with karma: 126 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1